# bug in svjour3 class file asymmetric margin

Tags: margins, sv-classes

I am trying to prepare a manuscript for submission to the Empirical SE and for some reason, I am finding that the generated pdf has asymmetric margins. That is, the left margin is way more smaller than the right margin, making the text look misaligned.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Usually, if this is for a journal submission, you should not be concerned with the layout since the journal editors will adjust things during final production to fit the standards of the journal.

However, if you wish to have equal margins, add

```
\setlength{\textwidth}{\dimexpr\pdfpagewidth-2in}
```

to your document preamble. This stems from the fact that the default odd/even margins is set to `0pt`, meaning the text block is flush (horizontally) with `\hoffset` - default is `1in` from the page boundary. Setting the `\textwidth` to `2in` shorter than the page width makes sure there is `1in` on either side of the text block to the page boundary.

[image]

```
\documentclass{svjour3}% http://www.e-publications.org/springer/support/spr-chicago.html
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\setlength{\textwidth}{\dimexpr\pdfpagewidth-2in}% Equal left/right margins
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Note that margin paragraphs will be placed within the `1in` margin space.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not a bug. The journals that use `svjour3` such as the Hyperfine Interactions journal are printed on a bizarre paper size. I think it is A5 paper, but would appreciate if someone could confirm.

Comment: `Eur J Nucl Med Mol Imaging` uses `svjour3`, but page size 8.27 x 10.98 in. This is pretty close to the common area of A4 and letter paper, with the exception that the letter height (11 in ~= 27.94) seems converted to 27.9 cm ~= 10.98 in. Interestingly, A4 would bei 29.7 cm high.