# svjour3: h/v centering text on a4paper?

Tags: geometry, sv-classes

I am preparing a manuscript using svjour3. I would like to have the text (dimensions unchanged!) simply centred on a4paper rather than aligned to the top-right corner, given that svjour3 in all but twocolumn mode assumes some a5'ish page geometry.

I am using an excerpt from ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/svjour3/global/template.tex.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}%ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/svjour3/global/svjour3.cls
\smartqed
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\title{Insert your title here}
\author{First Author}
\institute{F. Author \at
              first address \\
              Tel.: +123-45-678910\\
              Fax: +123-45-678910\\
              \email{fauthor@example.com}}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\keywords{First keyword \and Second keyword \and More}
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
\blindtext
\section{Section title}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

I am aware of a previous [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130590/bug-in-svjour3-class-file-asymmetric-margin), but I don't want the margins to be simply balanced, I want the text dimensions to remain unchanged and have the text body centred as-is on a4.

I am also aware that this will be fixed for me in final editing, but I want to have it centred for my private purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the parameters `\oddsidemargin`, `\evensidemargin` and `\topmargin` to the suitable values. It just requires some arithmetic and taking into account that there is a “fixed origin” one inch down and one inch right the paper.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[smallextended,a4paper]{svjour3}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\smartqed

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{\dimexpr(\paperwidth-\textwidth)/2-1in}%
  \setlength{\evensidemargin}{\oddsidemargin}%
  \setlength{\topmargin}{%
    \dimexpr(\paperheight-\textheight)/2-\headheight-\headsep-1in}%
}

\begin{document}

\title{Insert your title here}
\author{First Author}
\institute{F. Author \at
              first address \\
              Tel.: +123-45-678910\\
              Fax: +123-45-678910\\
              \email{fauthor@example.com}}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\keywords{First keyword \and Second keyword \and More}
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
\blindtext
\section{Section title}
\blindtext\blindtext
\blindtext\blindtext

\end{document}
```

The header is not taken into account, so the text block is centered.

[image]